# parsing json from onClick event

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

In my app I have two views that parse json from my website and it works great. The last issue i have is where i am entering a number in an edit text box and attaching it to my URL to add the user to the database. That works but when that event is launched I want to parse that json. Right now it just launches the website.

My question is how do i start that intent instead of launching right to the website. I have a JSONParser and two jason activities that work great. here is my code. I am also saving the edit text field to my sd card so the user can call it again when he comes back to that view. I know how to parse the json i just do not know how to call it from the onClick event into another view.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences mysettings2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String st1 = mysettings2.getString("THEME_PREF", "Blue");
    if(st1.equals("Blue"))
      {setTheme(R.style.Theme_Holo_blue); }
    if(st1.equals("Red"))
      {setTheme(R.style.Theme_Holo_red); }
    if(st1.equals("Green"))
      {setTheme(R.style.Theme_Holo_green); }
    if(st1.equals("Wallpaper"))
      {setTheme(R.style.Theme_Transparent); }
    if(st1.equals("Holo"))
      {setTheme(R.style.Theme_Holo); }

    setContentView(R.layout.getscore);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider));

      edttext= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      Button tutorial2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      tutorial2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://example.com/user/"+edttext.getText() +"?token=dYG8hW5TY4LBU8jfPb10D3IcsSx8RTo6"));
            startActivity(intent);

              try {
                  File myFile = new File("/sdcard/my_IdNumber_file.txt");
                  myFile.createNewFile();
                  FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                  OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                          new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                  myOutWriter.append(edttext.getText());
                  myOutWriter.close();
                  fOut.close();

              } catch (Exception e) {

              }
        }
      });   

          btnReadSDFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReadSDFile);
          btnReadSDFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    // write on SD card file data in the text box
try {
    File myFile = new File("/sdcard/my_IdNumber_file.txt");
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    String aDataRow = "";
    String aBuffer = "";
    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
        aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
    }
    edttext.setText(aBuffer);
    myReader.close();

} catch (Exception e) {

}
   }
```

this is my JSONParser activity

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONArray jarray = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
          int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

          if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line);
            }
          } else {
            Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
          }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jarray = new JSONArray( builder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jarray;

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to parse json at the time of launching activity then parse it onCreate();

Comment: yes that is how i am parsing my json in my other activities.They just launch when the activity is launched. this activity needs the onClick to add the user to my database. the onClick is what launches it and right now that is just accessing my json code webview.. when that event is launched how do i do that?

Comment: means u want to do parsing onClick?? and if yes then on clicking what??

Comment: do one thing make a setter and getter class and just before sending intent at in onClick parse your json and at that time set all those values in that setter and getter class and at the time of launching that activity get all those data.

Comment: yes i want parse json on my onClick event. it is listed in my code example.

Comment: not sure you read what i wrote. the onClick event goes to my website and diplays the php code. I know how to parse json. i just do not know how to call it from the onClick event which is clearly in my code above. please read fully what i posted.